# Explicit construction of Hamilton's counterexample for Implicit Function Theorem in Frechet Space

Tags: analysis, inverse-function-theorem, diffeomorphism

In his famous paper on Nash-Moser Theory, Hamilton mentioned in Counterexample 5.5.2 that a rotation $f: \theta\mapsto\theta + 2\pi/k$ on a circle can be "pushed a little bit" so that the new diffeomorphism only has $0$ as a $k$-periodic point, but $f(\pi/k)\neq3\pi/k$. My question is: is there any reference where Hamilton's construction was explicitly expressed? How can one "push" the rotation to obtain a diffeomorphism that only has $0$ as its $k$-periodic point?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider $g : \theta \mapsto \theta + 2\pi/k + \epsilon(1 - \cos \theta)$ for small $\epsilon$

Comment: Thank you Paul. I think your construction should work for me.